# Objective lens and Eyepiece of a compound microscope

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, lenses, microscopy

Why is the objective lens always powerful than Eyepiece of a compound microscope?
Will it not work if Eyepiece is more powerful?
In a book it is given that Eyepiece has larger focal length.

Comment: That's exactly what I said to another question like this. That's because you have to magnify a virtual image. Unlike a telescope, the object you look at finds itself in front of the objective focus.

Comment: Ok.......Thanks

Comment: the eyepiece is usually x10 and the objective is usually from x4 to x100. I don't think the objective has to be more powerful than the  eyepiece